# What's difference between Stackless and stackfull coroutines in Kotlin(Android)?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-developer-api

After reading some articles I figure out **Stackless**

> - means that the coroutines don’t have their own stack, so they don’t map on the native thread

*. so the first point is how it differs from **stackfull**
and in kotlin, if the coroutine helps us to manage **asyn** process. so how do these two different coroutines (Stackless and  stackfull) work.
because I am unable to find out its function/syntax/scope or any things else in kotlin coroutine. because I am unable to figure out where is mention which scope or function is Stackless or which of stackfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not important to know the the distinction to be able to use coroutines in Kotlin.

Kotlin coroutines are stackless: You can only call suspend functions from inside other suspend functions.

To boil it down to a very simplistic definition, a stackful coroutine model would let you suspend or yield from anywhere. A stackless model is restricted to suspending only from inside coroutines, but the benefit is that it is lighter weight. Also, it's probably more feasible to retrofit to an existing language. I don't know any details about the Kotlin coroutines implementation under the hood, but I would bet it would be have been near impossible to implement a stackful model and still compile as Java bytecode.